# gitlabci integration with sonar

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab-ci, devops, gitlab-ci-runner

Hi Everyone I’m trying to integrate with the sonar below is the **error** i am facing

> Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project XXXXX: Unable to register extension fr.cnes.sonar.plugins.icode.check.ICodeSensor from plugin ‘icode’: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project XXXXX: Unable to register extension

My code is java 11 and I have added the related dependency.

Can anyone help me in this one?

Answer (score 0):

The version of Sonar i-Code CNES plugin you use is not compatible with your java version (11).

Update your version of Sonar i-Code CNES plugin to >2.0.0 and it will work.